# How do I use iCloud to sync Pages documents from iPad to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, pages

I use pages on my iPad for documents. [Apple says](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/documents.html) that I can have everything that is in Pages on my iPad shared on my iPhone using iCloud.

How do I configure that?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure iCloud is turned on.
2. Open Settings > iCloud, and turn **On** "Documents and Data" if it is off.
3. If you are on iOS 6 on your iPhone, and not connected to wifi, open Settings > General > Cellular, and make certain "iCloud Documents" is **On**.
4. Verify that you are signed into the same iCloud account on both devices.
5. Install the Pages app on your iPhone, and on your iPad.
6. Open Pages on your iPhone. If you have created documents on your iPad, it may take a few moments for your iPhone to download them.

In addition, you may find [this how-to resource](http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/) helpful in setting up iCloud.

Comment: You may need to click a button in Pages on the original device telling it to share to iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bassplayer7's list, if you want to sync to a Mac, you would need OS X 10.8.

I use iCloud syncing between my Mac, iPad and iPhone for all three iWork programs. As a professional who frequently presents at conferences, I rely on iCloud to always have the latest version of my presentations, quoting system and forms on my gear.

Before you go hog-wild and build everything on your Mac, start out with a test file with the fonts and formatting you want use and ensure cross-device compatibility. iOS has a subset of Mac fonts available.

Comment: I've never seen - on Apple's website - or experienced, that one must have a Mac, or even a PC, in order to sync two iOS devices. Could you possibly provide a link that would support that? He didn't mention that he had a Mac, so we may be able to assume he doesn't.

Comment: Sorry... My assumption on the part of the computer.

Comment: You don't need a Mac to sync two iOS devices. You need a Mac if you want to sync to a Mac...